# FlatList not working inside BottomSheet on Android

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, bottom-sheet

I am using `gorhom/react-native-bottom-sheet`

The issue I am facing:

I have a `FlatList` inside a `BottomSheet`, I am able to scroll in `FlaLlist` on ios but it is not working on android.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After a lot of research, I was able to resolve the issue by using `BottomSheetFlatList` instead of `FlatList` from the same package.

```
import { BottomSheetFlatList } from "@gorhom/bottom-sheet";

<BottomSheetFlatList
        ref={ref}
        initialNumToRender={3}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item?.id}
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
        maxToRenderPerBatch={3}
        windowSize={7}
        data={dat}
        renderItem={renderItem}
      />
```

By doing so, it started working fine on android too.

But as I also wanted my `Flatlist` to auto-scroll using ref on a particular event.

After some research and because of the great documentation of `@gorhom/bottom-sheet`. I found out the solution in the troubleshooting section of the docs.

But as a developer, `StackOverflow` is our first go-to place for every issue. So, I decided to post the answer here.

**ANSWER**

Due to wrapping the content and handle with TapGestureHandler & PanGestureHandler, any gesture interaction would not function as expected.

To resolve this issue, please use ScrollView & FlatList from react-native-gesture-handler provide instead react-native.

```
import {
  ScrollView,
  FlatList
} from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
```

find the original answer here-
https://gorhom.github.io/react-native-bottom-sheet/troubleshooting

Comment: I have the problem, that when I use FlatList instead of BottomSheetFlatList only iOS works, but when I use BottomSheetFlatList, the list is ALWAYS empty ‍♂️. HEEEEEEEEELP I'm totally clueless

Comment: thanks!that saved med some time

Comment: thanks for this. I am a bit confused though. Should we be using ScrollView,
and  FlatList from 'react-native-gesture-handler', or BottomSheetFlatList?

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same problem, this is how i fixed the issue.

❌ Remove this import from your code

```
import {
  ScrollView,
  FlatList
} from 'react-native';
```

✅ Add this code or use this import

```
import {
  ScrollView,
  FlatList
} from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
```

Answer (score 1):

Using raw-bottom-sheet [raw-bottom-sheet](https://github.com/nysamnang/react-native-raw-bottom-sheet) and set "dragFromTopOnly" as true, and any touch operation can be performed i will mention
example below:

```js
 <RBSheet
        ref={refRBSheet}
        dragFromTopOnly={true}
        customStyles={{
          wrapper: {
            backgroundColor: "transparent"
          },
          draggableIcon: {
            backgroundColor: "#000"
          }
        }}
      >`
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

After struggling a whole day, I was able to solve this issue. Here is how I did that:

```
import React, {useRef, useMemo, useCallback, useState} from 'react';
import {TouchableOpacity, View, ActivityIndicator,Text} from 'react- native';
import {FlashList} from '@shopify/flash-list';
import {s} from 'react-native-wind';
import BottomSheet from '@gorhom/bottom-sheet';
import {
PanGestureHandler,
ScrollView,
GestureHandlerRootView,
} from 'react-native-gesture-handler';


const SearchResult = ({navigation, ...props}) => {
const bottomSheetRef = useRef(null);
const panRef = useRef();

const snapPoints = useMemo(() => ['35%', '65', '88%'], []);
const [sheetIndex, setSheetIndex] = useState(1);


const handleSheetChanges = useCallback(index => {
setSheetIndex(index);
}, []);

const gestureHandler = e => {
if (e.nativeEvent.translationY > 0) {
setSheetIndex(1);
} else if (e.nativeEvent.translationY < 0) {
setSheetIndex(2);
}
};

return (
<View style={{flex:1}}>
<BottomSheet
    ref={bottomSheetRef}
    index={sheetIndex}
    snapPoints={snapPoints}
    onChange={handleSheetChanges}>

      <PanGestureHandler ref={panRef} onGestureEvent={gestureHandler}>
        <View style={[s`flex-1`]}>
          <FlashList
            overrideProps={{
              simultaneousHandlers: panRef,
            }}
            estimatedItemSize={hp(22)}
            showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
            contentContainerStyle={{
              flexGrow: 1,
            }}
            data={data}
            keyExtractor={item => `${item.id}`}
            renderScrollComponent={ScrollView}
          />
        </View>

  </BottomSheet>
</Container>

);
};

export default SearchResult;
```

1. First wrap your Flatlist/FlashList or ScrollView in
   PanGestureHandler
2. Add a ref to PanGestureHandler and add the same ref to FlatList
   with overrideProps={{
   simultaneousHandlers: panRef,
   }}
3. Creare sheetIndex useState and pass it to BottomSheet
4. setSheetIndex on BottomSheet onChange method
5. Call onGestureEvent method on PanGestureHandler and setSheetIndex
   according to your requirement